# How to rearrange the links available in header in magento 2.0.2?

Tags: overrides, magento-2.0.2

To Rearrange the Header links(ie to bring the `My Wishlist` link at last)in magento 2.0.2 (parent-theme:blank) I just overrided the `default.xml` file in

`vendor/Magento/module_wishlist/view/frontend/layout/`

into

`app/design/frontend/<my_vendor>/<my_theme>/Magento_Wishlist/layout`

and added `after="authorization-link"` to it like,

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" after="authorization-link"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

But the order of the links didn't change. when I do it directly in `vendor/Magento/modules_Wishlist/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` changes are taking place.
Kindly help me.
Should anything be done additionally in order to override a layout file?

Comment: Please put your layout file inside

`app/design/frontend/<my_vendor>/<my_theme>/Magento_Wishlist/layout/override/theme/Magento/blank`

Instead of `app/design/frontend/<my_vendor>/<my_theme>/Magento_Wishlist/layout`

Comment: Please let me know if it works.

Comment: No it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share the path where did you put your layout xml file ? Also what is the name of your parent theme are you using ?

Comment: Do you have `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at top of your file?

Comment: yea I do have that specified

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Is it working right now? :)

Comment: @Yagnesh Ponkiya The path you specified didn't work. was it the exact path to override the layout file?

Comment: @Ramya, Yes it is exact if your parent theme is **blank**, if your parent theme is **luma** then replace **blank** with **luma**

Comment: @YagneshPonkiya yea my parent theme is blank but the changes are not getting applied. I tried the instruction you gave. When I do the same change in `vendor/Magento/module_wishlist/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` its happening. only inside my theme it is not working. Is there any other go?

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your xml file with this code,

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Link" name="wish-list-link" after="-"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Remove cache and try again.

Comment: Kindly check my code above. I have did that already. Also I cleared my cache

Comment: check updated code and keep only above code in your theme xml file.

Comment: No it is not changing :( Is there anything else that i should do in order to edit the overriden xml files?

Comment: THis is the way for getting xml file into theme and override those xml.

Comment: But am not getting any changes done

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Try following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="wish-list-link" destination="top.links" after="authorization-link />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Kindly check the my code in the question. I have given what you have mentioned.

Comment: Not exactly, you are using <block name="wish-list-link", and it should be <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link"

Comment: I tried. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you update your question with latest version of file?